# Is the Manias version of "Sanki Tousen" available as a single?

Tags: akibas-trip

## Question

Has the Manias version of "Sanki Tousen" been made available for sale, or, alternatively, is there an announcement that it will not be made available for sale? It is, notably, not part of ["Akiba's Collection"](http://vgmdb.net/album/64457), unlike all the other EDs.

## Background context

So, in *Akiba's Trip: The Animation*, there are these three characters, Mayonaka Matome, Denkigai Niwaka, and Arisa Ahokainen. Within the show, they form an idol unit called "Manias".

These three characters are voiced, respectively, by TAKAHASHI Rie, KOUNO Marika, and NAGAKU Yuki. In real life, they constitute an idol unit called "Earphones".

The "trademark" song of the Manias, so to speak, is a song titled "Sanki Tousen" (サンキトウセン). They perform this song as an insert in episode 3 and again in episode 11. "Sanki Tousen" performed by Manias is the ED for episode 4.

Separately, Earphones (the real-life idol unit) performs this same song as the ED for episode 3. The Earphones version of "Sanki Tousen" is track #3 on the album ["Akiba's Collection"](http://vgmdb.net/album/64457).

You might be sitting there wondering why I'm asking this question, given that I've just pointed out that Manias and Earphones consist of exactly the same people. What difference could there possibly be between the two versions of the song?

Well, it turns out that the Manias version is discernibly sung in-character, while the Earphones version isn't. This is easiest to detect with Nagaku Yuki, whose character voice (Arisa) differs most significantly from her regular singing voice. A careful comparison of the two versions of the Arisa solo verse that begins "*seseragi*" will make it clear that the two versions are subtly different.

Answer (score 2):

And alas, it turns out the answer to my question is that the Manias version of "Sanki Tousen" will indeed not be made available for sale. The comments on the [official YouTube upload of the TV-sized Manias version of "Sanki Tousen"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKZejMtFPU0) say as much:

> ※こちらの「まにあーずver.」の楽曲はアニメ放送用の音源を特別に掲載しております。
>   　CDには収録されませんので、ご了承ください。

(Roughly: "This is a special upload of the "Manias version" of the song, using the audio from the television broadcast. Please be aware that it will not be included on the CD.")

What a shame.